# Anylogic showing "event loop exception null" when I change the time unit after inputting the number

Tags: anylogic

This appears every time when I add a block and want to change the delay time. At first I input the number in the field in the rectangle, and then when I click on the time unit option in the circle, I will get this "event loop exception".

[image: 1]

If I change the time unit first and then the delay time, the change in delay time will not be saved and I have to change it again. I have no clue why this happens.
I'm using Macbook and the Anylogic version is the newest.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen and it may be related to the Mac version. Make sure you run the latest AnyLogic version, obviously.

In addition, delete your Workspace folder, sometimes this solves these kinds of issues (back it up, of course).

On Windows, you can find it in `C:\Users\MyUserProfile\.AnyLogicProfessional\Workspace8.8`, but you should be able to find the equivalent location on your Mac :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have deleted the workspace folder but unfortunately it didn't work. I may send an email to the Anylogic team and report this problem.